# Fastest way to find a vector in a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

My code is:

```
struct TileIdx { int mRow; int mCol; };

typedef std::vector<TileIdx> TileChain;

bool IsChainInChains(const TileChain& chain, const std::vector<TileChain>& chainArray);
```

The profiler shows that `IsChainInChains` is the bottleneck of my code.
I need the fastest way to implement this function.
We may assume, that `chainArray` is already sorted (Which way? It's up to you).
We may also assume that mRow and mCol won't be more than 100 (i.e. `mRow * 100 + mCol` is a valid `int` for sorting purposes).
I don't include my current implementation intentionally in order community not just to analyse my code, but propose new solutions.

Comment: minus 1 for failing to provide a current solution for no good reason.  It makes your question worse.

Comment: @Yakk I explained my reason. I don't just want my code to be analysed, but search for different approaches. This way the question is more common, thus more useful for community in the future.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of much useful information, I suggest using a binary search. For that purpose, use the standard library function [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).

```
auto it = std::lower_bound(begin(chainArray), end(chainArray), chain, comp);
```

where `comp` is the predicate used for the sorting `chainArray` and is a *strict weak ordering*.

Note that `std::vector` has an `operator<` that performs a lexicographical comparison of its elements. This would get used by `std::lower_bound` if called with three arguments. So if you implement `bool operator<(TileIdx, TileIdx)` as a strict weak ordering, you could omit the use of `comp`:

```
bool operator<(TileIdx rhs, TileIdx lhs) { .... }

std::sort(begin(chainArray), end(chainArray));

....

auto it = std::lower_bound(begin(chainArray), end(chainArray), chain);
```

Comment: Please specify which useful information is absent in the question.

Comment: @deko We don't know if you're using a binary search. We don't know if you're already using `std::loser_bound`.  There is no way to know why your implementation is "slow". Maybe there is no way to speed it up.

Comment: I got your point. I don't use `std::lower_bound`. I'll try your way! Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a vector of vectors ? If your other actions on your data can be slower, a good idea can be using a set of vector. See this small example :

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct TileIdx { int mRow; int mCol; };

typedef std::vector<TileIdx> TileChain;

bool operator < (const TileChain& t1, const TileChain& t2)
{
  if(t1.size() < t2.size())
    return true;
  if(t1.size() > t2.size())
    return false;
  for(unsigned long int i = 0; i < t1.size(); ++i)
  {
    if(t1[i].mRow < t2[i].mRow)
      return true;
    if(t1[i].mRow > t2[i].mRow)
      return false;
  }
  return false;
}

bool IsChainInChains(const TileChain& chain, const std::set<TileChain>& chains)
{
  return chains.count(chain) > 0;
}
```

You then have to choose your container with respect to your objectives. For your information, time needed by these actions is :

- Insert a new chain in Chains takes O(log(n)) for `set`, O(1) for `vector`
- Find a chain in Chains takes O(log(n)) for `set`, O(n) for `vector`
- Sort the chains in Chains is already done in `set`, takes O(n*log(n)) for `vector`

Then, as you can see, if you don't often modify Chains but check very often in it, `std::set` is a good solution.